# Refactor the below code to utilize very minimum space even for large data

Tags: java, algorithm

"A train has wagonCount , wagons indexed as 0,1,......wagonCount-1.Each wagon must be filled in the constructor of the Train using the fillWagon function.Which accepts wagon's index and return the wagon's cargo.The code below works, but the server has enough memory only for small train.Reactor the code so that server has enough memory even for large train?"

"Thinking we can convert the Hashtable collection to arrays, but no idea how to start, please help. or any idea would be great help. "

```
import java.util.function.Function;
public class Train {
    private Hashtable<Integer, Integer> wagons;

    public Train(int wagonCount, Function<Integer, Integer> fillWagon) {
        this.wagons = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < wagonCount; i++) {
            this.wagons.put(i, fillWagon.apply(i));
        }
    }

    public int peekWagon(int wagonIndex) {
        return this.wagons.get(wagonIndex);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Train train = new Train(10, wagonIndex -> wagonIndex);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Wagon: " + i + ", cargo: " + train.peekWagon(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `int[]` it consumes less memory.
It is the most optimal structure to keep integers. `Hashtable<Integer, Integer>` has a complex structure and huge overhead on storing the numbers, Even `Ineger[]` consumes alot more memory then int[]. So the best structure is array of primitives. Have a look at good explanation [Memory usage of Java objects](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml).

We use index of array to access to the element by required position, instead of `Hashtable.get` it's required less cpu resources:

```
public class Train {
    private int[] wagons;

    public Train(int wagonCount, Function<Integer, Integer> fillWagon) {
        this.wagons = new int[wagonCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < wagonCount; i++) {
            this.wagons[i] = fillWagon.apply(i);
        }
    }

    public int peekWagon(int wagonIndex) {
        return this.wagons[wagonIndex];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Train train = new Train(10, wagonIndex -> wagonIndex);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Wagon: " + i + ", cargo: " + train.peekWagon(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @i.bondarenko. will this sill satisfy the given condition in the question i.e. "Reactor the code so that server has enough memory even for large train". if yes then i'm happy if you explain little bit more about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a requirement to fill all wagons *during the execution of the constructor*, then there is just no way to store an arbitrary number of wagon contents in memory, when that memory has its size limited to some small constant. Sure, using an `int` array will take a bit less memory than a map, but it still grows linear to the input size.

If however, it is allowed to defer the actual storing of the wagon contents, then you could use the constructor to keep a reference to the callback function, and only call it when `peekWagon` is called. You could still use the little memory that is available for storing *some* of the wagon contents, but only for the last queried *k* wagons. That way, you will have in memory what is queried regularly, but will need to retrieve (again) the contents when that particular wagon is not (or no longer) in memory. You would then call the callback function again.

This assumes of course that the callback function will not have undesirable side-effects, and that it will always return the same value when passed the same argument.

If these assumptions are OK, your code could look like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {
    static int maxSize = 4;
    private LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> wagons;
    private Function<Integer, Integer> fillWagon;

    public Main(int wagonCount, Function<Integer, Integer> fillWagon) {
        this.wagons = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        this.fillWagon = fillWagon;
    }

    public int peekWagon(int wagonIndex) {
        int content;
        if (!this.wagons.containsKey(wagonIndex)) {
            if (this.wagons.size() >= maxSize) {
                // Make room by removing an entry
                int key = this.wagons.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey();  
                this.wagons.remove(key);
            }
            content = this.fillWagon.apply(wagonIndex);
        } else {
            // Remove entry so to put it at end of LinkedHashMap
            content = this.wagons.get(wagonIndex);
            this.wagons.remove(wagonIndex);
        }
        this.wagons.put(wagonIndex, content);
        return content;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```